# WordPress doesn't apply styles even though they are loaded

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying out the [JointsWP](http://jointswp.com/) WordPress starter theme, the Sass version.

I put the theme in the themes folder and activate it and everything works fine.

Then I compile the Sass files without changing anything and all styling on the page disappear.
I'm using compass RubyGem to compile.

The HTML is still linking to the stylesheet and I can open it and view it in the browser, and all the styles are there.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='joints-stylesheet-css'  href='http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/hljod/library/css/style.css?ver=1.5(Sass)' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I've tried compiling to the minified version and then back to the expanded version, still no styles loaded.

I have also tried hard refresh (empty cache and hard reload in Chrome Dev Tools) and another browser.

Comment: Can you give a URL to where you are trying this so we can see what is going on?

Comment: is it really being loaded ?

Comment: I'm developing on a local machine so I don't have an URL to show you. I think it's being loaded. I took two screenshots: [the source code](http://i.imgur.com/spfazQb.png) and [the stylesheet](http://i.imgur.com/WEgGQhf.png) I get when clicking on the link in the source code. Chrome Dev Tools don't pick up any styles though.

Comment: If the Chrome dev tools don't show any styles for the elements that you're targeting and you're certain that the stylesheet is being loaded, then you're probably not using the right selectors.

Answer (score -1):

There were a couple issues with some versions of Foundation that causes styles to not display when compiling. Those issues have been fixed in Foundation (and JointsWP).

Comment: I currently have this same issue and I have recently downloaded jointsWP. As soon as I did 'bower update' in my case I lost styling. I did this as any new styles defined wasn't being applied.  But now all style have been completely removed.